# How to let a table note go to the next page after a tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a `tabularx` table which is followed by a `\floatfoot{...}` (from the package `floatrow`) which contains some notes. My table is fitted on one page but I want the note in the `\floatfoot{...}` to go to the next page? How can I do that?

Or, is there any alternative way that I can attach some notes to my table on the next page after the table?

This is a simple code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{- ...}
    \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{lYYYcYYY}
    \toprule

 ...A table which fits on one page...

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}}%
  \label{...}%
  \floatfoot{A note that I want it go to the next page.}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**
So I found the following solution.

After the table `\end{table}` I add `\clearpage` and then write my description in `\begin{spacing} ... \end{spacing}` as follows.

```
  \clearpage
  \begin{spacing}{0.95}{\footnotesize \textbf{Continued from the previous page} - A long caption and description of the table...}
 \end{spacing}
```

I also put all of the table and the description in the `\afterpage{...}` so they stick together regardless of the rest of the document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: Please make your document example compilable and test it before publish it in your question. Also try populate table with some dummy content that will its size will be close to your real table. In general is not smart idea to have footnote from table on the next page. Make your question more clear.